# Rejection sampling from a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, simulation

I am running a Monte-Carlo simulation and I sample from various normal distributions. I was just wondering, is there a way by which I can increase the probability of selecting a point from the tails (i.e., $[-5\sigma,-3\sigma]$ and $[3\sigma,5\sigma]$) as compared to the probability associated with the interval $(-3\sigma, 3\sigma)$?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: @gung Could you give me any insights? Thanks.

Comment: As it stands your question is unclear. If you arbitrarily increase the probability of selecting from the tails compared to the center, you're no longer sampling from a normal with variance $\sigma$ (and if that's okay, it's easy - sample from something with higher probability in the tails -- like a normal with large variance). What are you trying to achieve, exactly? Are you trying to do some kind of importance sampling?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. It isn't importance sampling really. I am essentially keen on obtaining a larger percentage of values from the tails as I want to see how these will effect the final output of my Monte-Carlo Simulation. However, the samples I am obtaining are from parameters which have their variabilities modelled through Normal Distributions

Comment: Not certain I correctly understood your meaning, but if you're simulating a normal location-mixture of normals, that would be a normal with a larger variance.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, it is a normal location-mixture of normals. May I know why increasing the variance would help? I was wondering if I could do something like the picture I've added to the original question, except with a _slight_ hump in the middle as well.

Comment: I simply mean that's what it *is*: If your $\mu_i\sim N(\mu_0,\tau_0^2)$ and your $X_i|\mu_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$, then unconditionally, $X_i\sim N(\mu_0,\tau_0^2+\sigma^2)$. But perhaps you're supposed to be simulating to see that. (Is this for some subject?)

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you very much! This is probably a silly question, but may I ask why $\mu_i$ and $X_i|mu_i$ are different? I'm sorry I'm not able to use equations.

Comment: $\mu_i$ is the mean of the individual normals. You generate a normal-mean mixture of normals by simulating the mean from its normal distribution, then simulating the observation from it's own normal distribution with the mean just generated (this is the conditional formulation). Or you could simulate the data directly from the normal distribution with the larger spread (an unconditional formulation). $\quad$ By the way, what does your diagram represent, exactly?

Comment: @Glen_b The diagram was obtained from a code which was meant to increase the probability of drawing a sample from the tails of a distribution. The code in Matlab is as follows: `x=0:0.01:1; y=icdf(x);
icdf=@(uni)interp1(x,y,uni);
%plot some example data
hist(icdf(rand(10000000,1)),1000);`                                     Another method I was told to consider was given that the cdf of the distribution is known, the parts of the normcdf between [-5sigma,-3sigma] and [3sigma,5sigma] could be normalized to a integral of 1 to increase probability of drawing samples from the tails.

Comment: It seems like not enough detail is in the framing of your question. I would not have guessed from the way your question was asked that this was the kind of thing you were after. It feels like something relevant is missing.

Comment: @Glen_b I am very sorry. The code is definitely off and doesn't do what I want it to do. I just want to choose samples from the tails at a higher probability than I would choose those from $(-3\sigma, 3\sigma)$. My overall procedure involves _sampling randomly from 65 Normal Distributions for each MC Iteration, inputting these values into an equation and getting a result_ I want to explore the effects of data samples from the tails now. Shall I just increase the variance as you suggested? Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: That does clarify somewhat. There's an infinite number of ways to sample from the tails 'with more probability'. What do you need to achieve?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your response. I actually don't know what to expect from this method and therefore don't have anything in particular that I want to achieve. I just want to compare this particular sampling method to a random sampling method that I previously used.

Comment: Then you could sample from literally *any* distribution with more probability out there in the tails of the original distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry for pestering you, but how would I actually do this? Could I look to scale the integral of the tail portions to 0.5? How would this effect the rest of the distribution? Thanks again.

Comment: Do what in particular? I just pointed out there's an infinite number of things that would seem to fit what you're describing; can you narrow it down?

Comment: I would want to increase the probability of selecting a number from the tails to 70% so $[-5\sigma,-3\sigma]$ would have a probability of occurrence of 35% and so would $[3\sigma,5\sigma]$. And $[-3\sigma,3\sigma]$ would have a probability of occurrence of 30%. I don't know how to narrow it down any further, so I hope this is enough information.

Comment: @Glen_b I fear I haven't provided enough information. I'm pretty much a novice in Statistics and I was just wondering what you meant by _narrow it down_? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, your additional information certainly helps, but there's still many ways that might be done. Do you need the resulting distribution to have any particular shape within those ranges?

Comment: @Glen_b I don't have a particular shape in mind. I just need the percentages of occurrence associated with those ranges to be satisfied.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is with a mixture of uniform distributions.

Comment: @Glen_b So, you're suggesting sampling from Uniform Distribution instead of Normal Distribution? If so, is there still a way by which I can hope to do this by continuing to sample from Normal Distributions?

Comment: You can't really do it with *a* normal (you can make it higher by changing $\sigma$, but not that high) - but in any case why would it make more sense to sample from a normal in that case? (Incidentally, your picture isn't sampling from a normal)

Comment: @Glen_b Unfortunately, I need to sample from Normal Distributions as the various parameters which I eventually substitute into an equation and run a Monte Carlo on, are each Normally Distributed.

Comment: The sort of thing yo have in your diagram is a mixture of two normals (or, in effect, a normal with a random sign attached). If you can do that, you can get the probabilities you ask for.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for all your time and patience. One last question I have is, what does "normal with a random sign attached" mean?

Comment: If I take, say a normal with mean $10$ and standard deviation $1$, its pdf is a hill centered at $10$. If I multiply draws from it by a randomly chosen (50-50) value that's either $-1$ or $+1$ (which half the time makes it a N(-10,1) instead), then I get two hills of probability, one around 10 and one around -10, each half as "high" as the original. This is a mixture of two normals. By carefully choosing $\mu$ and $\sigma$, so that it has about a 70% chance of being above 3 and about a 30% chance of being below 3 (as long as $\sigma$ also isn't too big), then we can do the same thing with it.

Comment: @Glen_b I think you have just made my code for generating the above figure much easier. Thanks again. With choosing $\mu$ and $\sigma$, in order to ensure that I have 70% of the data within the tail 'distributions', would it just be a trial and error process?

Comment: No, it's simple. In fact, you can choose $\sigma$ (as long as it's not too big relative to the distance between the bounds, probably some value smaller than 1, like .5 or .7 or something of that order) and then derive $\mu$ in simple fashion. Or slightly less simply, choose $\mu$ as long as it's not too far above $3$ and derive $\sigma$. So there's a collection of possibilities.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks a lot. I'm sorry for being daft, but how did you calculate the means for those sigma?

Comment: An outline of the calculation (corrected) is in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after discussion in comments, I think it might be clear enough to hazard an answer to the question.

It seems that a symmetric-about-0 location-mixture of two normals is required, such that the probability of being in (0, 3) is about 0.15 and in (3, 5) is about 0.35 (and the same on the other side of 0).

This can be done; we'll do the positive component and the negative one will simply be the same but with $-\mu$ in place of $\mu$. The positive component should therefore have approximately 0.3 chance of being in (0, 3) about about 0.7 chance of being in (3, 5), since these probabilities will be halved when we select each half with probability 0.5.

Since almost all the probability for this positive part must lie in (0,5), and $\mu$ must exceed 3, $\sigma$ should probably be less than 1 (so that not too much probability is above 5).

Like so:

[image]

For a given $\sigma$ we need $P(X<3) = 0.3$, so $P(\frac{(X-\mu)}{\sigma}<\frac{(3-\mu)}{\sigma})=0.3)$, or $\frac{(3-\mu)}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.3)$ where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse cdf of the standard normal. Hence $\mu = 3-\sigma\, \Phi^{-1}(0.3)$.

Calculating in R:

```
> sig=c(0.6,0.8,1.0); data.frame( sigma = sig, mu = 3-sig*qnorm(0.3) )
  sigma       mu
1   0.6 3.314640
2   0.8 3.419520
3   1.0 3.524401
```

Check how much probability is above 5 for the $\sigma=1$ case:

```
> pnorm(5,3.524,1,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.06997195
```

That's perhaps a little high, we only get (0.7-0.07)/2 = 0.315 in (3,5). Checking $\sigma=0.8$:

```
 pnorm(5,3.4195,0.8,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.02409863
```

That looks reasonably good, almost 0.34 in (3,5). (The value for $\sigma=0.6$ is 0.349.)

You can use $\mu = 3-\sigma\, \Phi^{-1}(0.3)$ with whatever value of $\sigma$ you prefer, or you can manipulate the equation so that $\mu$ is given and $\sigma$ is calculated.